# ANT xsl, conditional replace

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

I have a XML file where I want to replace the password for a specific user. With the use of ANT and xsl file I want replace the old password ie password1

xml file

```
<connector-factory connector-name="JmsAdapter" location="eis/wljms/Src">
    <config-property name="username" value="username1"></config-property>
    <config-property name="password" value="password1"></config-property>
    <log>
      <file path="/var/log/logfile.log"></file>
    </log>
</connector-factory>
<connector-factory connector-name="JmsAdapter" location="eis/wljms/Src">
    <config-property name="username" value="username2"></config-property>
    <config-property name="password" value="password2"></config-property>
</connector-factory>
<connector-factory connector-name="JmsAdapter" location="eis/wljms/Src">
    <config-property name="username" value="username3"></config-property>
    <config-property name="password" value=""></config-property>
    <log>
      <file path="/var/log/logfile.log"></file>
    </log>
</connector-factory>
```

xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="config-property/@value[. =  'username1']">
            <config-property name="username" value="username1"/>
            <config-property name="password" value="PASSWD_DBLINK"/>
        </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

build xml

```
<target name="JmsAdapter">
   <property name="tmp.file" value="JmsServer-oc4j-ra.tmp"/>
   <xslt in="oc4j-ra.xml" out="${tmp.file}" style="JmsServer-oc4j-ra.xsl">
   <outputproperty name="method" value="xml"/>
   </xslt>
   <replaceregexp file="${tmp.file}" match="PASSWD_DBLINK" replace="${PASSWD_DBLINK}" byline="true"/>
   <xmltask outputter="simple" source="${tmp.file}" dest="${tmp.file}">
   <remove path="/oc4j-connector-factories/connector-factory/config-property/@value[.='username1']"/>
   <remove path="/oc4j-connector-factories/connector-factory/config-property/@name[.='password']"/>
   </xmltask>
   </target>
```

The result obviously is, that the password is changed to the correct value, however because of this line

```
<remove path="/oc4j-connector-factories/connector-factory/config-property/@name[.='password']"/>
```

all the other passwords where deleted and this is not what I want. Without this statement the password entry is appended to the file, and I don't want this either.

My question is how to replace the password only in the correct path, where for example value=username1, and not everywhere else.

Comment: And have you considered using [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) instead of a whole XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I seem to run into the same issue. I think I am at the end of my knowledge / creativity to fix this issue.

Comment: In addition a simple find and replace does not do the trick, as I am only interested in replace the password for a specific user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the whole thing with `xmltask` using the `replace` option with a slightly more specific XPath expression:

```
<xmltask outputter="simple" source="${tmp.file}" dest="${tmp.file}">
  <replace withText="${PASSWD_DBLINK}"
     path="/oc4j-connector-factories/connector-factory[
              config-property[@name='username'][@value = 'username1']
           ]/config-property[@name='password']/@value"/>
</xmltask>
```

Here I'm using a predicate at the `connector-factory` level to select only the `connector-factory` with username "username1", and then modifying its password property.

Alternatively with XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- to pass in the new password value from Ant -->
  <xsl:param name="newPassword" />

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replace the password value for username1 only -->
  <xsl:template match="connector-factory[
          config-property[@name = 'username'][@value =  'username1']
        ]/config-property[@name = 'password']/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="$newPassword" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and call it from Ant with

```
<xslt in="oc4j-ra.xml" out="${tmp.file}" style="JmsServer-oc4j-ra.xsl">
  <param name="newPassword" expression="${PASSWD_DBLINK}"/>
</xslt>
```

Comment: I tested the xmltask, which is much easier to implemented and works like a charm. Thanks again!